# Getting hourly data of every minute data from mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a data flowing into the mongo collection for every minute and I use below query to get data between the specified time ranges,

```
mongo_client.db("db")
      .collection(collection)
      .aggregate([
        {
          $addFields: {
            timestampISO: {
              $toLong: "$periodicMessageBase.messageTimestamp",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            deviceId: deviceId,
            periodicMessageBase: {
              $exists: true,
            },
            timestampISO: {
              $lt: "1694008207000", // unix timestamp
              $gte: "1695002207000",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            DeviceID: "$deviceId",
            Timestamp: "$timestampISO",
            L1_VoltageAngleMean: {
              $ifNull: [
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: ["$periodicMessageBase.vAngle.meanVal", 0],
                },
                0,
              ],
            }
          },
        },
      ])
      .sort({
        Timestamp: -1,
      })
```

but when I search for long time ranges instead of getting data for every minute is it possible to get data for each hour ?

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: [{
  "deviceId": "1108d0bb20c8",
  "seqNo": 46643,
  "periodicMessageBase": {
    "messageTimestamp": "1693997460124",
    "vThd": [
      {
        "meanVal": 2.490000009536743,
        "maxVal": 2.5399999618530273,
        "minVal": 2.430000066757202
      },
      {
        "meanVal": 2.7100000381469727,
        "maxVal": 2.7699999809265137,
        "minVal": 2.6600000858306885
      },
      {
        "meanVal": 2.549999952316284,
        "maxVal": 2.5999999046325684,
        "minVal": 2.4800000190734863
      }
    ]
  }
},

]

Comment: sample data will be like above for every minute flowing into mongo collection

Comment: Instead of converting the `Date` to a number, better do the other way around, i.e. `{$match: {"periodicMessageBase.messageTimestamp": {$lt: new Date(1694008207000)}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mongoDb version is 5.0 or higher, one option is to replace your `$project` stage with these 2 stages:

```
{$project: {
      _id: 0,
      DeviceID: "$deviceId",
      Timestamp: {$dateTrunc: {date: {$toDate: "$timestampISO"}, unit: "hour"}},
      L1_VoltageAngleMean: {
          $ifNull: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$periodicMessageBase.vAngle.meanVal", 0]}, 0]
       }
}},
{$group: {
    _id: "$Timestamp",
    DeviceID: {$first: "$DeviceID"},
    L1_VoltageAngleMean: {$avg: "$L1_VoltageAngleMean"}
}}
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gLQlbQFAW3f)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked the way I exactly wanted